# Can I add a tag within a tag in Microdata?

Tags: schema.org, microdata

I am in the process of tagging content for a forthcoming training course.  I am sort of getting the hang of it. However I have as my description:

```
<span itemprop="description">This 2 day certificated course meets the requirements of all management standards for ....</span>
```

But I also would like to declare the duration of the course.  My question is can I do so within the tag?

So instead I have:

```
 <span itemprop="description">This <span itemprop="duration">2 day</span> certificated course meets the requirements of all management standards for ....</span>
```

Or is that likely to confuse Google (etc.)?

Answer (score 0):

This is fine (except for the value of the [`duration` property](http://schema.org/duration), which should be "in ISO 8601 date format").

Every conforming Microdata parser will extract the following values:

- `description`:

  > This 2 day certificated course meets the requirements of all management standards for ....
- `duration`:

  > 2 day